# WP: Display a specific custom post type list (archive) and that post content (single) within a custom page template

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Here's what I have.

1. I have a custom page template that I use for a parent page and all child pages created under that parent. This template dynamically displays the parent, "About", and all child pages, "Contact", "Terms", "Privacy", etc. on the left navigation side bar and cooresponding content as the user clicks around.
2. I have a custom post type, "Press", and the client wants this as a new menu choice on said left navigation side bar i.e.; "About", "Press Releases", "Contact" . . . and so on . . .
3. I assume I need to inject some logic into the custom page template that currently has the basic query for "page" content. I'm guessing the logic would be something like "Get me some normal page content BUT if the user clicks on "Press Releases" I'll engage another alternate query that pings the CPT "Press", grab that post_id and display the content accordingly.

Am I off track here or just having a really bad brain fart today?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the custom post type to the wp_list arguments?

```
<?php wp_list_pages( $args ); ?> 

<?php $args = array(
    'child_of'     => 0,  //parent page 
    'exclude'      => '',
    'include'      => '', //parent page 
    'post_type'    => 'page, Press' //include custom post type
); ?>
```

Comment: wp_list_pages for the left navigation in the template.

Comment: Really I need to pieces to this page template.

1. code to just display a list of previous press release titles
2. code to then display post content when a user clicks on the above permalink

Comment: this is only on my local dev pc.